# jbuilderでjsonを表示する際、綺麗にインデントして表示されるにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

現在railsでapiを作成しています。 
そこで、jbuilderを使ってるのですが、ブラウザで確認した時に出力結果がすべて横並びになっていてとても見づらいです。 
どうすれば綺麗にインデントして表示されるのでしょうか？ 
お手数ですが、ご教授お願いしたいます。

Comment: JSONを整形して出力したいということでしょうか？(人間が読むときに整形するツールに貼り付ければ良いとは思いますが)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通りです。
それはツールを使う以前にブラウザで例えばlocalhost:3000/api/v1/posts/のようなURLにアクセスした際、整形された状態で表示させることはできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

開発時に確認する目的であれば、ブラウザのアドオン類を導入するという方法があります。
(例) JSONView: https://addons.mozilla.org/ja/firefox/addon/jsonview/

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
これで開発が捗りそうです！
ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

chromeにも
json-viewer
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh
このようなadd-onがあります。開発で使うだけならこのようなadd-onを使用するだけで随分違うかと思います。

curlなどのコマンドラインで叩いた結果を見やすくしたいのであれば、
jq
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/
このツールがメジャーです

```
curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/ | jq '.'
```

こんな感じで渡してあげれば見やすいかと

ユーザーにも見やすく表示してあげたいのであればそのapiを叩くクライアントかviewを作成してそこで綺麗に整形してあげるのがわかりやすいかと思いますが・・・

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
まさにこういうことを知りたかったです！助かりました！
ありがとうございました。